# Change Telerik grid columns based on Appsetting

Tags: grid, telerik-mvc, configurationmanager

I have a Html.Telerik().Grid() that is bound to a model in my MVC view. I want it to return a link based on a value in the appsettings in the web.config. Basically, if this is the dev server then show the links but not on the production server, is that possible? I use Ajax binding and my bound column looks as follows:

```
columns.Bound(f => f.TechnicalKey)
       .ClientTemplate("<# if (FileName != 'status.txt' && StatusText=='PROCESSED') { #><a href='/AType/DownloadAFile/<#= TechnicalKey #>'>Download</a> <# } else { #>Not available<# } #>")
       .Title("").Filterable(false);
```

I want the status.txt to be a link on development but not on production (this is how it is now)

Thank you.
Jack

Comment: What the problem with the column definition you currently have is? I guess you can replace the check for the txt file with value from the appsettings web.config if you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually achieved this by adding a property in the domain object as follows:

```
    public bool isProduction
    {
      get
      {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActivationURL"].Contains("production");
      }
    }
```

and then in the view I had:

```
    .Columns(columns =>
                  {
                    columns.Bound(f => f.TechnicalKey)
                      .Template(f => { %>
                                          <% if (f.StatusText == "PROCESSED")
                                              {
                                                if (!f.isProduction || f.FileName != "status.txt")
                                                {                          
                                                  %><a href="/AType/DownloadAFile/<%= f.TechnicalKey %>">Download</a><%
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                  %>Not available<%
                                                }                                
                                              }
                                              else
                                              {
                                                %>Not available<%
                                              } 
                                            %>
                                    <% })
                      .ClientTemplate("<# if (StatusText=='PROCESSED') { if(!isProduction || FileName!='status.txt') { #><a href='/AType/DownloadAFile/<#= TechnicalKey #>'>Download</a> <# } else { #>Not available<# }} else { #>Not available<# } #>").Encoded(false).Title("").Filterable(false);
```

This way I cater for the initial server bound data and the later Ajax bound data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the client template in a different way depending on the fact your application is deployed or not:

```
if (/* some check to see if on production which is specific to your implementation */) {
columns.Bound(f => f.TechnicalKey)
       .ClientTemplate("<# if (FileName != 'status.txt' && StatusText=='PROCESSED') { #>Download <# } else { #>Not available<# } #>")
       .Title("").Filterable(false);

} else {
columns.Bound(f => f.TechnicalKey)
       .ClientTemplate("<# if (FileName != 'status.txt' && StatusText=='PROCESSED') { #><a href='/AType/DownloadAFile/<#= TechnicalKey #>'>Download</a> <# } else { #>Not available<# } #>")
       .Title("").Filterable(false);
}
```